# <img> as EventHandler in JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, event-handling

I'm trying to bind a click handler for my search field to an `img` or class with `on()` but it will not work. I'm adding the image with this code:

```
jQ('#psc').append('<div class"psc-search-wrapper" style="float:left;"><input class="psc-input"></input><img class="psc-search-image"title=""/></div>');

var table = $('#tbl-me').DataTable();
table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx) {
    var searchHandler = $(".psc-search-image");
    jQ('.psc-input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('click', searchHandler, function() {
        table.column(colIdx).search(this.value).draw();
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var table = $('#tbl-me').DataTable();
        jQ('#psc-search').on('click',function(){
            var pscValue = jQ('.psc-input').val();  
            table.column(3).search(pscValue).draw();    
        });
```

Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should select the parent of the `<div class"psc-search-wrapper" ...` you just appended then select the child which is the `searchHandler`.

you can't select `jQ( '.psc-input', ...` you should select the parent then use `find()` to select it :

```
var myInput = jQ('#psc').find('.psc-input')
```

Comment: of course i can select  '.psc-input'  if i use  '.on( 'keyup change', function () ' it works but i will trigger this function on image click.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? you want to fire click event on input or image??

Comment: on image "psc-search-image"  , so if i click the image the function should be fired

Comment: function `on()` can only select the children of selected element not sibling. the `img` is not the child of `.psc-input`
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: first of all, I don't know what are you trying to do here `jQ('.psc-input', table.column(colIdx).header())` and second of all show me more codes of your html page that are related to this part

Comment: `<table id="tbl-me" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th role="columnHeader" colspan="1"></th>
            <th role="columnHeader" colspan="1" id ="psc"></th></tr>
</table>` its just a table,  im getting the column index to search in this column

Comment: It's still not clear to me but for handling an event on `<img>`, my best guess is this code `jQ('#psc').on('click', ".psc-search-image", function() ...` , if you have just one image and also I should mention that you forgot `=` in `<div class = ...`